# how to know if mongodb has more records to show

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to make a pagination system with ranges :

```
$hospitals=$qb->select('subtype','price','title','date','photos','description')
                ->field('active')
                ->equals(1)
                ->limit(10)
                ->field('date')
                ->lte($lastdate)
                ->sort('_id', 'desc')
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
                ->toArray();
```

Along with this data , I want to send a 'has_more' attribute because I've developed an infinite scroll and it would be meaningless to query data when you're sure it won't return anything.
I want to know how can I get the has_more boolean from the query above.

A way would be to calculate the total number of queries and compare with the limit , but I believe there is some way smarter and easier ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am implementing infinite scroll or pagination with mongo, I am using the following technique (I hope you will be able to adapt it to your doctrine).

If for example I have to show `X` elements per scroll/page. I am selecting `X+1` element. Then if exactly `X+1` element was selected I am selecting new `X+1` element (skipping the first `X`). But I output always only `X` elements.

If you have less than `X+1`, I output all of them and know that there is nothing else to show.

Another approach is not to bother with all this `+1` thing and only get `X` elements and stop right when you encounter an empty result. After this point of time, you just stop sending requests.

Comment: This i what I've done , Bro we have the same thinkings :D
I'll be a little bit more detailed so this is what I've done :
when the results are full I send an attribute in my json array named hasmore and its value is true , and in my javascript I always test on this variable to send request , when the results are empty , hasmore = false. and it doesn't send anything else